# USB tethering question

Tags: usb, internet, android, phone, tethering

I plan to switch from Windows to Ubuntu tomorrow but my PC doesn't use an ethernet cable because I haven't had a hole drilled in my wall and etc, and I'm using either my phone (Samsung Galaxy Trend Lite S7390) or my tablet (Vonino Onyx Qs) with USB tethering, and my question is: Does Ubuntu 14.04 support USB tethering from Android devices?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Android's USB tethering shows up as an USB RNDIS device, which has been supported in the Linux kernel for several years.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I had ti manually install the drivers on Windows 8 so I wasn't sure Ubuntu was gonna support it.

Answer (score 2):

yes for sure! you just have to enable it in your android settings:
[image]

if you got troubles or want more clients to use this connection, you can also establish a WiFi-hotspot in the same menu (as highlighted in the picture).