# wifi username and password

Tags: wireless

I am connected to a wireless network which has a password and user name .And i am running Mozilla through that network.How i connect my whole operating system to that network.
I mean i cant download any software or i cant run anything except Mozilla.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very confusing question, what do you mean when you say you use *Mozilla*? Mozilla Firefox? That's a browser, which cannot handle networking by itself. If you can browse through Firefox, congratulations, you ARE connected to the network.

This is the first guide that comes up when googling "ubuntu connect to wifi": https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-connect.html

How does this procedure differ from what you did to connect?

Quote from link:

> If you have a wireless hardware switch on your computer, make sure
>   that it is turned on.
>
> Click the network menu in the menu bar, and click the name of the
>   network you want to connect to.
>
> If the name of the network isn't in the list, select More Networks to
>   see if the network is further down the list. If you still don't see
>   the network, you may be out of range or the network might be hidden.
>
> If the network is protected by a password (encryption key), enter the
>   password when prompted and click Connect.
>
> If you do not know the key, it may be written on the underside of the
>   wireless router or base station, in its instruction manual, or you may
>   have to ask the person who administers the wireless network.
>
> The network icon will change appearance as the computer attempts to
>   connect to the network.
>
> If the connection is successful, the icon will change to a dot with
>   several bars above it. More bars indicate a stronger connection to the
>   network. If there aren't many bars, the connection is weak and might
>   not be very reliable.

Comment: wifi is proxy configured with user authentication. So, when i surf internet through mozilla firefox it automatically ask for authentication username and password. But problem came when i supposed to download any software through ubuntu software center and when installing anything through terminal...

Comment: A clarification question: is the authentication trough a web site login, or is it a username/password protected proxy? It's not likely to be both.

Comment: username and password protected.

Comment: OK, so you've configured FF to use an HTTP proxy, which in turn pops up an authentication dialog.

Sounds like a duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/82880/how-do-i-set-a-system-wide-proxy-with-a-username-and-password

Comment: yeah same question but when i apply the proxy system world wide ,it dont pop up anything and i cant set the username and password and i am new to ubuntu

Comment: And you tried setting the username and password in the proxy hostname, like in the link?

Comment: i dont know what is proxy hostname  and how to set username and password in it.

Comment: That is exactly what the link in my comment describes.

Comment: i cant open that link. it is blocked in my hostel wifi.

Comment: But the link is to askubuntu.com, same site we're having this discussion on...

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use the WiFi, and you haven't got a land line and modem, and you haven't got ethernet, you might be able to

- hook up your mobile phone to a USB port
- turn on [USB tethering](https://askubuntu.com/questions/649480/usb-tethering-question/649488#649488) on the phone
- connect to the internet through your phone, using the data allowance on your mobile phone plan

Comment: you dont  understand my question brother